# rails gem 'countries' - LoadError: cannot load such file -- iso3166

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I use `gem 'countries', require: 'iso3166'`.

When I try to start the server I got this error:

```
rake aborted!

LoadError: cannot load such file -- iso3166
/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ekoodo/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ekoodo/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ekoodo/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ekoodo/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ekoodo/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ekoodo/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ekoodo/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
/home/davide/Desktop/app/koodos/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/davide/Desktop/app/koodos/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/davide/Desktop/app/koodos/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ekoodo/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@ekoodo/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried running `bundle install` again, but it didn't help. I searched the web for similar problem but I dind't find any solution.

Any idea about what might cause the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your gemfile and bundle it again

```
gem 'countries', :require => 'countries/global'
```

`iso3166` module already added to the gem itself.

you can see documentation https://github.com/hexorx/countries

Comment: thank you @pitabas, I'll give it a try and let you know. the point is that I'm cloning a repo whith that gemfile already setup so I imagine at least once it worked

Answer (score 0):

Countries 1.2.0 and above requires a different include than previously. Since you are locked at 1.2.5, use the new require.

```
gem 'countries', :require => 'countries/global'
```

If that is still an issue, run `bundle install`.